# How to populate a dropdown using PHP and MySqli

Tags: php, mysqli

First time poster and wet-behind-the-ears programmer here, hope you guys can help me out!

I'm trying to create a dropdown list using php/html, and to populate it using a mysqli-call.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php

require_once 'forbindtilDB.php';

$result = performQuery("SELECT DISTINCT primaer FROM oevelser");

FOLLOWING TWO LINES ARE ONLY TO CHECK RESULT 'MANUALLY' IN UI:

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
echo $row['primaer'];

        ?>
     <html>
<body>
<form>
    <select> 
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
            {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['primaer'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['primaer']) ?>
            </option>
            <?php
            }  

        ?>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The dropdown is displayed, but it's not getting any contents besides 'Please select' (should be two options at this stage, more to come...)

Any hints on this?

Also, since I'm using DISTINCT to get data from a specific column in the table, should I use something else than 'fetch_assoc' to get my result?

Any input will be appreciated!

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: unexpected constants also

Comment: Oh my God, that was fast - Daan, you're absolutely correct, I added and 'i' to the function, and now it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: Daryl, could you elaborated about your point about constants? I'm not seeing any errors now...

Comment: @ErikLassen probably he is reffering to the line `FOLLOWING TWO ...` if that was actually in your code.

Comment: @Steve - you might be right - I put that there as an explanation to the reader (it's not in my actual code), but I can see how that may be confusing. I'll separate comments and code better next time :)

Comment: Also, thanks a lot to all of you for quick and useful responses - I think I'm gonna like this site a lot :)